# Trying to add player object to an array of players within my session

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a Lobby for a web game I'm working on and I want to add the person who is creating the lobby to the lobby's "Players" array. I'm using parse and I can't for the life of me figure out how to append just the player object into the array. Any help is great!

```
function createLobby(){
  var ses = Parse.Object.extend("Session");
    var query = new Parse.Query(ses);
    var exists = false;
    query.equalTo("sessionName", document.getElementById("lobby").value);
    query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length );
      if(results.length!=0){
        alert("Session already exists");
        exists = true;
      }
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });  
  if(exists==false){
      session.set("sessionName",document.getElementById("lobby").value);
      var Players = Parse.Object.extend("Player");
      var query = new Parse.Query(Players);
      query.equalTo("Name", "testName");
      query.find({

      success: function(results) {
        var query2 = new Parse.Query(Players);
        query2.get(results[0].id, {
          success: function(k) {
            console.log(k);
            session.add("Players", k);
           },
           error: function(object, error) {
              // The object was not retrieved successfully.
              // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
            }
      });
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
      });  

      session.save(null, {
       success: function(object) {
         $(".success").show();
       },
       error: function(model, error) {
        $(".error").show();
       }
      }); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're failing to understand how callbacks work. I recommend you read about JavaScript callbacks and promises. Here's how this should be written:

```
function createLobby() {
  var ses = Parse.Object.extend("Session");
  var query = new Parse.Query(ses);
  var exists = false;
  query.equalTo("sessionName", document.getElementById("lobby").value);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length);
      if (results.length != 0) {
        alert("Session already exists");
        return;
      }
      session.set("sessionName", document.getElementById("lobby").value);
      var Players = Parse.Object.extend("Player");
      var query = new Parse.Query(Players);
      query.equalTo("Name", "testName");
      query.find({
        success: function(results) {
          var query2 = new Parse.Query(Players);
          query2.get(results[0].id, {
            success: function(k) {
              console.log(k);
              session.add("Players", k);
            },
            error: function(object, error) {
              // The object was not retrieved successfully.
              // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
            }
          });
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
      });
      session.save(null, {
        success: function(object) {
          $(".success").show();
        },
        error: function(model, error) {
          $(".error").show();
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Actually, with parse the error function is not called unless there was an actual error. Even if it's not there it is still a success.

Comment: Ok, then you just move that piece of code into the `success` callback instead of the `error` callback. I've updated my answer.